# How to serialize object with file property

Tags: javascript, json

I am building a small catalog on the web, that details housing projects and enables users to download documents about them.

My data model is simple : a project owns a few inner properties and a collection of documents. A document owns a few properties itself and a file (the one that will be downloaded by the user).

There is also a back-office, where admins can add/delete/update projects. And this is where I struggle to do what I want.

On the javascript side, I am building objects representing projects and I would like to send them to the php side to perform the database tasks. Is there a way to serialize a whole projet with its attached documents (inculding the files) in order to send it from javascript to php ?

Comment: Yes, use `FormData` object. Or simply submit without Ajax

Comment: JSON.stringify() ... however i recommend NodeJS & MongoDB ...

Comment: @Justinas: FormData seems to do the job. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonasw: maybe your solution is better. But I'll try with FormData first, as It seems more rapidly usable to me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I answer to my post to get an accepted answer).*

I used formData as suggested by Justinas.

I found valuable info here : [Using Ajax to submit the form](http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using JSON.

```
var myPropertyCatalog = {...};
var myDataToSend = JSON.stringify(myPropertyCatalog);
```

This can be decoded by built in packages in most major languages. PHP can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I allready tried with JSON but did not succeed in sending the file content.
Does JSON include the file content too ?