# Sending a file object to api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send an object that contains attached files to server. Before calling the HTTP method, the object is populated with the attached files

```
   createIncident(data: any) {
        console.log(data)
        return instance.post(`v2/newIncident`, data).then(response => response)
    },
```

[image]

but in the request payload, the object is empty - why are the objects empty when I send them?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to send them as JSON?

Comment: File objects can't be serialized to JSON in the major browsers (at time of writing). Probably for security reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/how-can-i-serialize-an-input-file-object-to-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize object with file property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848477/how-to-serialize-object-with-file-property)

Comment: set Content-Type:multipart/form-data header